# how to change the videogular/ngx-videogular media source dynamically using the VgApiService

Tags: angular, videogular2

I have a new angular 15 project using angular/material 15 and videogular/ngx-videogular to display a playlist, however I am unable to change the video source using any of the know methods. it appears that ngx-videogular has removed the properties from VgAPI which is now VgApiService. I want to do something like this:

```
const currentMedia = this.api.getDefaultMedia();
this.api.removeMedia(currentMedia);
const newMedia = new VgMedia(this.api, { src: video.src, type: 'video/mp4' });
this.api.addMedia(newMedia);
```

but removeMedia is no longer a property of VgApiService and VgMedia can't be found. I also tried changing the source in the  element with:

```
 <video [vgMedia]="$any(media)" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" 
                  autoplay="true"  crossorigin>

   <source *ngFor="let video of video_list" 
          [src]="video_list[currentIndex].src" 
          [type]="video_list[currentIndex].type">
          
 </video>
```

none of these variations works the first video plays on repeat for the length of the playlist.  I would surely appreciate any suggestions here...Thanks